# is Passing query from react front end to feathers service good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, feathersjs, querying

I am using rematch(https://github.com/rematch/rematch) to in React JS, and for backend Its Feathers. If I want to fetch the records from database with certain conditions, I am able to pass the query from in API call in React code.
Ex.

```
const empData = await employeeService.find({
    query: {
        $and:[
            {employeeId: payload.empIId},
            {name:"ABC"}
        ]
    }
});
```

This directly passes the query to auto generated feathers service, and prvides me expected result too.

My question is, is it a good practice to pass these types of queries(May be more complex than this) from front end? Please elaborate the answer(what are the pros and cons etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do this successfully & extensively on several projects. It creates the greatest deal of flexibility.  Changes can be implemented in the client as opposed to requiring changes in both the client & server.

This should be done in combination with a server that does not trust the client.  The server should sanitize & rate-limit input queries to ensure that the client is not receiving anything it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Letting clients execute queries directly is usually a bad idea. You don't know the query beforehand, which means anyone can POST a manipulated query that will tie your database up, effectively DDOS-ing you. Since you don't check the input you can't defend yourself against such attacks.

It is always a good idea to validate input on every system boundary.

Comment: then what is the use of feathers auto generated services? Do I need to write custom API's along with those services for my custom queries?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I know Mongo, not feathers. I stay away from magic :)